# How to remove the hover effect on the brand name in the navbar section?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the brand name in the navbar the color changes to black, although i have assigned the color orange for the brand name.

I have tried the following:
display:none;
a:hover: none;

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zarocom GmbH</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarResponsive">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>`
```

Comment: `.navbar-brand:hover { color: orange}` Just override the default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Change color Override the **navbar-brand** class like below code

```
 <style>
  .navbar-brand{   
     color:orange !important;
      }
  </style>
```

If you want change color When hover set color `!important`, In case if you use any element call element name too **navbar-brand h1**

Comment: Another helpful tip. Use inspect in your user agent(browser). Select the element so that you can make change in your css. Once you achieve your goal, copy the same into your css file. If you use Chrome press ctrl+shif+I